# Azure Function Apps Hybrid Connections connect to Azure Load Balancer

Tags: azure-function-app, azure-load-balancer, azure-hybrid-connections

Regarding Hybrid Connections attaching the relevant documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections).

What we currently have is:

(WebApp) <--> (Hybrid Connection Manager) <--> (EndPoint A)

In the configuration of Hybrid Connection we specify:

- Hybrid Connection name
- Endpoint hostname (Hostname of VM endpoint)
- Endpoint port

What we need is instead of connecting to a VM, to connect to an Azure Load Balancer which will redirect the traffic to other VMs (e.g. main traffic - EndPointA & failover - EndPointB). So:

(WebApp) <--> (Hybrid Connection Manager) <--> (Load Balancer) <--> (Endpoint A)

The question is:
"Is this something feasible if we take into consideration that Load Balancer is not a VM so the connection manager (.msi) cannot be installed on Load Balancer (our new endpoint). If not what are the alternatives?"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After some research and testing found the solution!

(Hybrid Connection Manager) <--> (Load Balancer)

On this part in Hybrid Connection Manager we assign the IP of Load Balancer (as endpoint) and we need to install the client (connection manager .msi) in every "sub-endpoint" of Load Balancer!